# Bridge Card Orderings

Tags: combinatorics, card-games

Let's say 4 players, A, B, C , and D are playing bridge. (Each player is dealt 13 cards and random from standard 52 card deck).

What is the number of ways that all cards of two suits are split among players A and B?

> I got ${4\choose2}{26\choose13}{13\choose13}{26\choose13}{13\choose13}$. We first select which 2 suits go to players A and B then we select 13 cards out of the 26 for A, then there only remain 13 cards B can select so B takes the remaining. Of all 26 cards remaining, we give 13 to C and the rest to D

Comment: Your formula reach to $7 \times 10^{28}$ ; what is the total number of ways to deal 52 cards to 4 players ? is it consistent ?

Comment: @Lourrran I think I had a typo, now I have $6 \cdot {26\choose13}^2$

Comment: It is better. You should explain how you  obtain this formula. It is still wrong, but the error is very small. Maybe it is more simple to go step by step. Question 1 ) What is the probability that Black cards (spades + clubs) are dealt to A and B, and Red cards to C and D.  Edit : Sorry, it is correct. I was thinking inclusion/exclusion, but is is not needed.

Answer (score 1):

Your answer is correct. There are $\binom{4}2\binom{26}{13}^2$ ways that $A$ and $B$ receive all of the cards of two suits, where the order of cards within a hand does not matter.